# Tracing IP address of comments in Blogger.com

Tags: blogger, ip-addresses

If a comment is posted from a Google account on a blog hosted in Blogger.com, can the IP address of the person who has commented be traced by the blog owner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no tools provided inside Blogger to do this.

It's likely that Google do have tools to do it, but would only actually use them if a court ordered them to.